# Is there a way to grab the results of a fetch following an onClick event?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api, asynchronous

I have a basic application that allows users to look up bible verses. Is there a way to show the results of a fetch where I have placed: `<p>fetch results should show up here</p>` below? The procedure seems straightforward, but I am a little stuck. I have already tried returning the fetched data in my `this.getScripture(...)` method and then assigning that to a variable, like: `data = this.getScripture(...)` and then using `<p>{data}</p>` **however** I do not see anything when this happens, because the page was not refreshed perhaps..? Any help is needed. Thankyou.

**The UI that shows the fetched data:**

```
        <div>
            <ul className = "list-group">
                {this.state.posts.map((each) => (
                    <li key = {each.index} >
                        <Accordion>
                            <Card>
                                <Accordion.Toggle as={Card.Header} eventKey="0">
                                    <Button variant = 'info' onClick={()=>this.getScripture(each.book, each.chapter, each.verse)}><b>Click Me to Show/Hide Biblical Comparision</b></Button>
                                </Accordion.Toggle>
                                <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="0">
                                    <p>fetch results should show up here</p>
                                </Accordion.Collapse>
                            </Card>
                        </Accordion>
                    </li>
                    ))}
            </ul>
        </div>
```

**The Method that fetches the necessary data:**

```
getScripture(book, chapter, verse) {
    const url = '/api/bibleVerse' //communicates with an express backend
    var scripture = {
        bible_url: `https://getbible.net/json?passage=${book}${chapter}:${verse}&version=akjv`,
        book: book,
        chapter: chapter,
        verse: verse
    }
    fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        credentials: 'include',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(scripture)
    })
    .then((response) => response.text())
    .then((data) => {
        console.log(data)
        //return data..this (doesn't really work as I described in my description)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
    })  
}
```

Comment: You need to use state to achieve this. In your `then( data => { ... }` block, set state containing this data. You can then use that state in rendering. this.setState will cause a re-render using your new state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to change your code with

```
// first you need to use the arrow syntax to have access the the this object:
getScripture = (book, chapter, verse) => { 
...
.then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
    this.setState({data: data});
})
```

and in the other section

```
<p>{this.state.data}</p>
```